# Why are pandas frame columns hidden when redirected to stdout?

Tags: pandas

I have a python script that prints wide pandas tables. When I run my script in my terminal, the frames print perfectly, and I can see all columns. When I redirect to stdout or pipe to tee, most of the central columns are replaced with “...”. I tried increasing the maximum pandas width, and I get all the columns in stdout, but they are segmented. I will get 80 characters worth of columns going across, then the next 80 characters worth of columns printed below the table, etc until the entire table is displayed. Is there any way to get the entire table to print in one piece in stdout?

I tried the below command, which prints all columns, but only 80 characters worth at a time followed by the next 80 characters worth of columns below that etc.

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

Comment: Can you update your post with your code for the behavior to be reproducible, please?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to do this:

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Instead of this:

```
print(df)
```

Apparently, pandas was eliminating columns because it thought there was a restriction on the length of the output, but converting to a string gives the full text of each row.